# How to load and apply planet osm diff?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

Few months ago I donwloaded full planet.osm dump and imported it in postgresql database via osm2pgsql. Later I removed the dump file. Thats why I don't know the timestamp of my current osm data. How can I get this timestamp?

If I will know this timestamp, how can I download and import to my postgresql database the diff between this timestamp and now?

P.S.: import the full dump again is bad idea, it is too slow.

Comment: crossposted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54378/how-to-load-and-apply-planet-osm-diff + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958610/how-to-load-and-apply-planet-osm-diff

Comment: The answer is here:  https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54378/how-to-load-and-apply-planet-osm-diff  .  If nothing changes I will delete this post after one week.